# Libgdx Player rotation messing up

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to program a player that rotates towards the mouse and travels towards the mouse at a certain speed. I am using an orthographic camera, however as soon as I set the camera's position to equal the players position, the player rotation stops working and goes all over the place. I believe it might have something to do with the mouse coordinates using the screen and not the world x and y. I have tried unprojecting Gdx.inout.getY/X to no prevail. Any help is much appreciated.

I am using this code to follow player:

```
    cam.position.x = player.getX();
    cam.position.y = player.getY();
    cam.update();

And this code for rotation:
float mouseX = Gdx.input.getX();
                float mouseY = (480 - Gdx.input.getY());

                float originX = getWidth() / 2 + position.x;
                float originY = getHeight() / 2 + position.y;

                double angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - originY, mouseX - originX) * (180/Math.PI) + 90;

                if (angle < 0) 
                      angle += 360;

                rotation = (float) angle;

                direction.x = mouseX - position.x;
                direction.y = mouseY - position.y;

                double hyp = Math.sqrt(direction.x * direction.x + direction.y * direction.y);
                direction.x /= hyp;
                direction.y /= hyp;

                position.x += direction.x * 2;
                position.y += direction.y * 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried projecting (or unprojecting) the points?

```
ViewPort viewPort = new ... // which ever ViewPort you're using

Vector2 worldPoint = new Vector2(x, y);
Vector2 projected = viewPort.project(worldPoint);
```

or

```
Vector2 screenPoint = new Vector2(x, y);
Vector2 unprojected = viewPort.unproject(screenPoint);
```

Comment: Sorry im new to some of this stuff, so I create a new viewport and set it so my camera? What would my world point be? The position of the player?

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming you were already using a ViewPort. Do a search for StretchViewport (there a different Viewport's available, I'm using this one in my current project) - you should be able to find your answers that way...

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work using screen viewport and unpojecting that way.